# Use pyenv local python version with SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl, pyenv

My system comes with Python 2.7.6 installed by default. I need to use v2.7.8 so I've installed it using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv):

```
pyenv install 2.7.8
```

and set it up as the local version in the folder where my code resides with:

```
cd /path_to_folder
pyenv local 2.7.8
```

After this, I installed all the necessary packages into v2.7.8 using `pip install <package>`.

If I run:

```
$ cd /path_to_folder
$ python
```

I get the 2.7.8 version and I can run my code with no issues. But if I try to build my code within `Sublime 3` using the [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) package I get the default 2.7.6 version where none of the packages are installed.

How can I force `SublimeREPL` to build using the 2.7.8 version of Python I installed via `pyenv` instead of the system default 2.7.6 version?

Comment: I am using SublimeText 3 and it seems to include Python 3.3 inside itself.  When I bring up the console and type `import sys; print(sys.version)`, it confirms I'm using the built-in Python 3.3.  How did you get SublimeText to use a different Python in the first place?  Ahh, I see, you are using SublimeREPL, which on my system runs Python 3.5.  Investigating pyenv now

Comment: I too see the 3.3.3 version if I run `import sys; print(sys.version)` but I did nothing. SublimeREPL seems to pick up the system Python version by default.